# Python dataframe groupby by dictionary list then sum

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. The first named `mergedcsv` is of the format:
[mergedcsv dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E85Tz.jpg)

The second dataframe named `idgrp_df` is of a dictionary format which for each region Id a list of corresponding string ids.
[idgrp_df dataframe - keys with lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzT6A.jpg)

For each row in mergedcsv (and the corresponding row in idgrp_df) I wish to select the columns within mergedcsv where the column labels are equal to the list with idgrp_df for that row. Then sum the values of those particular values and add the output to a column within mergedcsv. The function will iterate through all rows in mergedcsv (582 rows x 600 columns).

My line of code to try to attempt this is:

```
mergedcsv['TotRegFlows'] = mergedcsv.groupby([idgrp_df],as_index=False).numbers.apply(lambda x: x.iat[0].sum())
```

It returns a `ValueError: Grouper for class pandas.core.frame.DataFrame not 1-dimensional.`

This relates to the input dataframe for the groupby. How can I access the list for each row as the input for the groupby?

So for example, for the first row in mergedcsv I wish to select the columns with labels `F95RR04`, `F95RR06` and `F95RR15` (reading from the list in the first row of idgrp_df). Sum the values in these columns for that row and insert the sum value into `TotRegFlows` column.

Any ideas as to how I can utilize the list would be very much appreciated.

Edits:

Many thanks IanS. Your solution is useful. Following modification of the code line based on this advice I realised that (as suggested) my index in both dataframes are out of sync. I tested the indices (mergedcsv had 'None' and idgrp_df has 'REG_ID' column as index. I set the mergedcsv to 'REG_ID' also. Then realised that the mergedcsv has 582 rows (the REG_ID is not unique) and the idgrp_df has 220 rows (REG_ID is unique). I therefor think I am missing a groupby based on REG_ID index in mergedcsv.
I have modified the code as follows:

```
mergedcsv.set_index('REG_ID', inplace=True)
    print mergedcsv.index.name
    print idgrp_df.index.name

    mergedcsvgroup = mergedcsv.groupby('REG_ID')[mergedcsv.columns].apply(lambda y: y.tolist())

    mergedcsvgroup['TotRegFlows'] = mergedcsvgroup.apply(lambda row: row[idgrp_df.loc[row.name]].sum(), axis=1)
```

I have a keyError:'REG_ID'.

Any further recommendations are most welcome. Would it be more efficient to combine the groupby and apply into one line?

I am new to working with pandas and trying to build experience in python

Further amendments:

Without an index for mergedcsv:

```
mergedcsv['TotRegFlows'] = mergedcsv.apply(lambda row: row[idgrp_df.loc[row.name]].groupby('REG_ID').sum(), axis=1)
```

this throws a KeyError: (the label[0] is not in the [index], u 'occurred at index 0')

With an index for mergedcsv:

```
mergedcsv.set_index('REG_ID', inplace=True)
columnlist = list(mergedcsv.columns.values)
mergedcsv['TotRegFlows'] = mergedcsv.apply(lambda row: row[idgrp_df.loc[row.name]].groupby('REG_ID')[columnlist].transform().sum(), axis=1)
```

this throws a TypeError: ("unhashable type:'list'", u'occurred at index 7')

Or finally separating the groupby function:

```
columnlist = list(mergedcsv.columns.values)
mergedcsvgroup = mergedcsv.groupby('REG_ID')
mergedcsv['TotRegFlows'] = mergedcsvgroup.apply(lambda row: row[idgrp_df.loc[row.name]].sum())
```

this throws a TypeError: unhashable type list. The axis=1 argument is not available also with groupby apply.

Any ideas how I can use the lists with the apply function? I've explored tuples in the apply code but have not had any success.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Did my answer help you solve your problem? Feel free to ask for clarifications!

Comment: Thank you @IanS your suggestions have been really useful in comparing the two dataframes. I realised that a groupby is required on the first dataframe. I have edited the original post to reflect the changes. But still have list errors. Any further advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: The first key error is because once you have set `REG_ID` as the index, the column is removed and you can no longer group by it. You could do it (with `groupby(level=0)`), but since `REG_ID` is not unique I do not think it's a good idea.

Comment: Regarding your second and third solutions, you call `groupby` on the row inside the `apply` function, but since the row is only a single row, there is nothing to group.

Comment: Finally, your last solution will not work because `apply` to a `groupby` object works very differently from `apply` to a dataframe. In the first case the function is applied to each group (i.e. sub-dataframe) independently, while in the second case it is applied row by row.

Comment: Have you tried `mergedcsvgroup = mergedcsv.groupby('REG_ID').sum().set_index('REG_ID')` and then running the last code again? I assume `sum` is the correct aggregation here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I have a simple solution with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6], 'C': [7,8,9]})
lists = pd.Series([['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['C']])
```

**Solution**

I apply a lambda function that gets the list of columns to be summed from the `lists` series:

```
df.apply(lambda row: row[lists[row.name]].sum(), axis=1)
```

The trick is that, when iterating over rows (`axis=1`), `row.name` is the original index of the dataframe `df`. I use that to access the list from the `lists` series.

**Notes**

This solution assumes that both dataframes share the same index, which appears not to be the case in the screenshots you included. You have to address that.

Also, if `idgrp_df` is a dataframe and not a series, then you need to access its values with `.loc`.